# Google Error Reporting running on Google Compute Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, stackdriver

I try to implement google error reporting using stackdriver on GCE (ref : https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/ruby#compute-engine).

And created a service account with generate a key and also already have setting IAM for Error Reporting write to it.

[image]

Try to provide the parameters to the staging environment config

```
config.google_cloud.use_error_reporting = true
config.google_cloud.error_reporting.project_id = ENV['STACKDRIVER_PROJECT_ID']
config.google_cloud.error_reporting.keyfile = "#{Dir.home}#{ENV['STACKDRIVER_KEY_FILE']}"
config.google_cloud.error_reporting.service_name = "service-name"
```

Make an error code on the controller looks like :

```
[88d1aac5-7d9f-4052-864f-9f5e51241e62] NameError (undefined local variable or method `test_error_reporting_stackdriver'
```

and also try on rails console :

```
2.6.5 :027 > promise = Google::Cloud::ErrorReporting.report Exception.new "Oh no!"
 => #<Concurrent::Promises::Future:0x00000000094cd728 pending> 
2.6.5 :028 > promise.state
 => :fulfilled
```

but error not being reporting on my console.

Is there anything missing from my configuration?

note :

I've successfully implement google logging using the same service account, using  :

```
config.google_cloud.use_logging = true
config.google_cloud.logging.project_id = ENV['STACKDRIVER_PROJECT_ID']
config.google_cloud.logging.keyfile    = "#{Dir.home}#{ENV['STACKDRIVER_KEY_FILE']}"
```

Comment: Stackdriver logs can take a LONG time to appear in the console. Are you sure you've given it adequate time? Do you have `config.google_cloud.use_error_reporting = true` in your code? (because it only enables itself in `production` if you don't have that set)

Comment: @anothermh I think `Error Reporting is enabled by default when Rails is running in production mode` based on ref, I mean staging is a mirror production mode

Comment: @anothermh I've make try an error yesterday, until today the logs not comming

Comment: If `Rails.env.production? == true` then it'll work automatically. Otherwise, set `config.google_cloud.use_error_reporting` manually to true.

Comment: @anothermh I've update my configuration, do you know about how long error reporting will be appear on console? If  it take a long time, I think not a make sense for "error reporting" because error reporting is a real-time alert.

Comment: @anothermh and one thing, correct me if I'm wrong, staging environment and production ennvironment is no differrent configuration, It's just different name

Comment: [Report an error manually](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-error_reporting#reporting-errors-manually) to test it. And no, staging is not production. They may have similar configs but the environments are different. Like I said, [if `Rails.env.production? == true`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-error_reporting/lib/google/cloud/error_reporting/rails.rb#L100) then it will work, otherwise it requires manual configuration.

Comment: @anothermh did you see my original post was updated with manual config and set to `true` and try to run manually also on rails console..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

The config on application side is fine, I totally forgot for enable Google Error Reporting API https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com/overview

that is the first thing and I'm missing it.